# What does 'tempering' mean in the passage?

Tags: meaning

The following is the excerpt from Obama's inaugural speech. What does the word, 'tempering' evades me. I look it up in the dictionary, to no avail. What does it mean in the context?

> They understood that our power alone cannot protect us, nor does it
>   entitle us to do as we please. Instead, they knew that our power grows
>   through its prudent use; our security emanates from the justness of
>   our cause, the force of our example, the ***tempering*** qualities of
>   humility and restraint.

Answer (score 1):

Google Dictionary says:

**act as a neutralizing or counterbalancing force to (something).**

"their idealism is tempered with realism"

synonyms:   moderate, modify, modulate; tone down, mitigate, palliate, alleviate, allay, assuage, lessen, reduce, weaken, lighten, soften, cushion;
qualify

The noun originally denoted a proportionate mixture of elements or qualities, also the combination of the four bodily humours, believed in medieval times to be the basis of *temperament*.